# Magento 2: Attribute set in custom product

Tags: magento2, custom-product-type

I've created new product type, defined in product_types.xml. Then, i've created product with my custom attribure set, but i don't see attributes from this set in admin.

Comment: Try to reindex ...

Comment: @Kothari nothing.

Comment: First check that attribute is created or not

Comment: @Kotharim it works if product type is simple.